# Suggestions on a web based rich text editor...that supports code blocks?

Tags: editor, richtextbox

I read this post:

[What is the easiest-to-use web "rich text editor"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21274/what-is-the-easiest-to-use-web-rich-text-editor)

and followed up with most of the suggestions, but haven't found any that supports code blocks -

What does stackoverflow use?

Thanks,

Sam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the editor StackOverflow uses is this one...

http://wmd-editor.com/

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/).